# How to compute machine learning training computation time and what are reference values?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, time, artificial-intelligence, training-data

in many forums and documents on the internet we hear about "short" and "long" learning and prediction computation time for machine learning algorithms. For example the Decision Tree Algorithm has a short computation time as compared to Neural Networks. But what it is never mentioned is what is "short" and what is "long".

Could you please clarify which unit you would use to measure computation time? Maybe "seconds per sample"? And what are reference values, so that I can predict if it takes 1h, 1day or 1Week?

Thanks
Kind regards
G

Comment: This is something you should measure on your own, since at least for neural networks, it depends on CPU/GPU, network architecture, hyper-parameters, and input dimensionality.

Comment: Your question doesn't fit here particularly well, but is a worthy question.  Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues.

Comment: However, I *will* answer parts of this within the range of Stack Overflow applications ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, any benchmark figures depend critically on information you've neglected to provide: the domain you're in, the topology in use, input sizes and output complexity.  The amount of training time depends on all of those factors, the framework for the implementation, and the platform you're on.

For instance, I can fully train

```
model class: 4-node linear neural network 
model: AND gate
framework: none; Python / SciKit
platform: 32-node Intel Broadwell(tm) box
```

in three iterations, far less than a second.

However, given

```
model class: CNN 
model: ResNet-50
framework: TensorFlow
platform: Single-card, 4-core Intel Haswell(tm) box
```

The training will take days.

The units in which we express the speed are those convenient to the audience for the domain.  For processing still images, we usually specify the image size and report in images/sec (sometimes called "Hertz").  For audio input, it's usually an average clip length and clips/sec -- but if the processing is **O(n)** on the input time, it's often given as a scalar.  Machine translation is expressed in words or sentences (of a typical length) per second.

For data center managers, the training is also given in electrical power: how many kilowatt-hours does it take to train a particular model?

---

You asked for reference values: again, read the posting guidelines.  Reference values for standard (i.e. popular and stable) models are published on line; you should research these before you post, to help focus your question.  They are useful once you have know *your* application well enough to adjust those figures (optimized for customers) to your own environment.

For instance, let's say you're trying to train ResNet-20 on the 100-class ImageNet data base.  However, all you can find are figures for ResNet-50 on the hardware you have.  Fortunately, ResNet is roughly linear in scaling by depth: you can take a comparable ResNet-50 training time and multiply by 20/50 to get an estimate for yours.  My experience suggests that you should expect a training time 40-50% of the ResNet-50 time.

Similarly, if the figures you find are only for the 1000-class ImageNet, multiply by 100/1000 to get the training time to expect.

---

Overall, however, your general question has no real answer, other than to start doing your research, run your individual model, and learn how it operates, how it scales, how it responds to changes in hardware architecture, input size, model topology, focused training, etc.